# Euler number of symmetric cube of the tautological bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $E$ -is a tautological two-dimensional bundle (rank $n=2$) over complex Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(2, 4)$ ($2$-dimensional planes in $C^4$). I'm trying to compute the Euler number $\oint_{\operatorname{Gr}(2, 4)}{e(S^3E)}$.

Where $S^3E$ -is a symmetric cube of the bundle $E$.

My thoughts about this question are the following:

I know that the Euler class of a complex vector bundle is always equal to the top Chern class.

For tautological vector bundle $E$ the top Chern class is $c_4(\operatorname{Gr}(2, 4)) = 6c_2(Q)^2$ where $c_2(Q)^2$ is the generator of $H^8(\operatorname{Gr}(2, 4); \mathbb{Z})$. Also we have the splitting principle $c(S^{p} E)=\prod_{1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \ldots \leq i_p \leq n} (1+x_{i_1}+\ldots+x_{i_p})$ (possibly it may be useful in this situation). I don't know how to continue computations for symmetric cube. Please, can you explain these computations in more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By splitting principle
$$
c_4(S^3E) = 
3x_1(2x_1+x_2)(x_1+2x_2)3x_2 =
9x_1x_2(2x_1^2 + 5x_1x_2 + 2x_2^2) =
9x_1x_2(2(x_1 + x_2)^2 + x_1x_2) =
18c_1(E)^2c_2(E) + 9c_2(E)^2.
$$
It remains to note that $c_1(E)^2c_2(E) = c_2(E)^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

In schubert for maple

```
grass(2,4,c,tan);
                    currentvariety_ is Gc, DIM is 4

chi(symm(3,Qc));
                                  20
```

The 27 lines on a cubic surface in ${\Bbb P}^3$.

```
integral(chern(4,symm(3,Qc)));
                                  27
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In general I want to undertstand why this euler number is equal to 20. Please can you explain this in more details?